# Functor preserves kernels iff it's left exact

Tags: homological-algebra

I'm trying to understand the proof to a statement in Rotman's 'Introduction to Homological Algebra': Proposition 5.25, p. 240:

> Let $F :_R\text{Mod} \to \text{Ab}$ be a covariant functor. Then $F$ preserves kernels iff $F$ is left exact.

It's my understanding that in this context, kernel means a solution to a pullback (where one of the objects is zero), or inverse limit if we construct the pullback definition in terms of the appropriate inverse system.

Here's the proof that's given:

Note: Example 5.12 (iii) just shows how the kernel can be seen as a pullback of a particular system.

> Let $0 \to A' \xrightarrow i  A \xrightarrow p  A''$ be exact. If $F$ preserves kernels, then $(FA', Fi)$ is a kernel of $Fp$, and Example 5.12 (iii) shows that $Fi$ is an injection, that is, $F$ is left exact. Conversely, if $F$ is left exact, then $(\text{ker } Fp, Fi)$ is a kernel of $Fp$ so $F$ preserves kernels.

I don't see how either direction of his proof shows what was stated. If someone could fill in the details of what I'm not seeing, I'd appreciate it.

I was able to show the first implication, but with considerably more work than what was stated as a proof.

For the first implication, we assume $0 \to A' \xrightarrow i A \xrightarrow p A''$ is exact. I want to show that $0 \to FA' \xrightarrow{Fi} FA \xrightarrow{Fp} FA''$ is exact which means I need to show three things: $\text{ker }(Fi) = 0$, $\text{im }(Fi) \subseteq \text{ker }(Fp)$ and $\text{ker }(Fp) \subseteq \text{im }(Fi)$.

1. Clearly, we can show that $(A', i)$ is a kernel of $p : A \to A''$, and so $(FA', Fi)$ is a kernel of $Fp : FA \to FA''$ by hypothesis. This tells us one of the three things we needed: $Fp \circ Fi = 0$ which means $\text{im }(Fi) \subseteq \text{ker }(Fp)$.
2. He say's "Example 5.2 (iii) shows that $Fi$ is an injection", but that's not really immediate. All Example 5.2 (iii) says it that the kernel of a function is a pullback. In this case $(0, z)$ is a kernel of $i : A' \to A$ where $z : 0 \to A'$ is just the zero map. Since, by hypothesis, $F$ preservies kernels, we have that $(F0, Fz)$ is a kernel of $Fi : FA' \to FA$. In particular, we have $\text{ker } Fi \cong F(0) = 0$ because kernels are unique up to isomorphism, which tells us $Fi$ is injective.
3. As $(FA', Fi)$ is a kernel of $Fp : FA \to FA''$, we can use the definition of pullback or equalizer and choose $X := \text{ker } (Fp)$ and $h : \text{ker }(Fp) \to FA$ to be the inclusion. Clearly $Fp \circ h = 0$ so there exists $\theta : \text{ker }(Fp) \to FA'$ such that $Fi \circ \theta = h$, in particular for $x \in \text{ker }(Fp)$, we have $x = h(x) = Fi \circ \theta(x)$ which means $x \in \text{im }(Fi)$.

The converse also requires quite a bit more work than is stated. Am I missing something , or is it expected to have to go through all these details to arrive at the same conclusions? My concern is that I'm missing something that I shouldn't be that makes my life much easier? I'll add my work in any case.

Suppose $F$ is left exact and let $p : A \to A''$ be a morphism and $(K, i)$ be it's kernel. It can be shown that $i$ is injective because $\text{ker }(p)$ is also it's kernel and kernels are unique up to isomorphism. We can just say: without loss of generality, $K = \text{ker }(p)$ and $i$ is the inclusion map. So we have an exact sequence $0 \to K \xrightarrow i A \xrightarrow p A''$. By hypothesis we have $0 \to FK \xrightarrow{Fi} FA \xrightarrow{Fp} FA''$ is exact. We want to show that $(FK, Fi)$ is a kernel for $Fp : FA \to FA''$. We know that $(\text{ker }(Fp), j)$ where $j : \text{ker }(Fp) \to FA$ is the inclusion map is a kernel of $Fp : FA \to FA''$. Using the definition of pullback we can choose $X := Fk$ and $h = Fi$ with $Fp \circ h = 0$. This means that there exists $\theta : FK \to \text{ker }(Fp)$ such that $j \circ \theta = Fi$. We can show that $\theta$ is an isomorphism, which means that $FK$ is a kernel of $Fp : FA \to FA''$ as desired.

Comment: I think it's simpler depending on your definition of left-exactness. If you're assuming left exact as preserving limits then I think this is in general not true (of course, it will preserve monos). If you're assuming that it preserves exact sequences except the surjection, then it's true. In this case, one implication is trivial. Conversely, if it preserves kernels, then the left arrow will be a mono and then the kernel of $p'$ will be preserved, but $i$ is a mono (so it's image is isomorphic to $A'$).

Comment: Actually, the functor has to preserve $0$ and $\oplus$ as well.

Comment: @user40276, the definition for left exactness that I'm using is that if I have a left exact sequence, when I apply the functor, I get a left exact sequence. You said one implication is trivial, how so? I just showed above how much work it took to show each case. As for your converse, I don't understand what you mean by "the left arrow will be a mono"?

Comment: If it's left exact, then it will preserve kernels. The point is that given a morphism $f: A \rightarrow B$, then $ker(f) \rightarrow A \rightarrow im(f)$ is exact, so you can apply your functor. And, by the left arrow I mean what you called $i$. As I said before, left exactness (according to your definition) is equivalent, in abelian categories, to preserve finite limits (equivalently, as Zhen Lin noticed, to preserve finite colimits or limits (they're equal!) and kernels).

Comment: Now that I'm seeing this again. I think that the statement is wrong unless $F$ is additive.

Comment: @user40276, do you have an example of a non-additive functor $F : _R\text{Mod} \to \text{Ab}$ that doesn't preserve $0$?

Comment: Sure, pick for instance $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and  $- \otimes M$ for some abelian group $M$.

Comment: @user40276 why would that not preserve 0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You actually have to require that $F$ is an additive functor, then Rotman's proof says it all.

About the first implication, you should maybe first clearly understand that

i) if $A' \xrightarrow i  A$ is a mono, then $A' \cong Im(i)$ (try to prove it directly);

ii) if $0 \to A' \xrightarrow i  A \xrightarrow p  A''$ is exact, then $i = ker(p)$ (also easy to prove just using the definitions);

Then you have that $ KerF(i) \cong F(Ker(i)) \cong F(0) \cong 0 $ (using here functor's additivity). So $F(i)$ is mono and $KerF(p) \cong F(Ker(p)) \cong F(Im(i)) \cong F(A') \cong ImF(i)$.

This means that $0 \to F(A') \rightarrow   F(A) \rightarrow F(A'')$ is exact.

Comment: So to be more precise, $F$ only has to respect null objects (which is a priori weaker than being additive).

Answer (score 2):

One useful relevant fact:

$$0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$$
is exact iff $A \xrightarrow{f} B$ is a kernel of $B \xrightarrow{g} C$.